# Magento Bundle Product Coupons

Tags: magento, configuration, product, coupon

i have a question about the Coupon System of Magento.
Is it posible to enable a Coupon for a Bundle Product. The Coupon will work on the Total Price of the Bundle Product Configuration and not by the single Sub Product. I found no solution of Configuration in den Coupon Managment.

The Coupon must work with the SKU of die Bundle Product (Fix SKU, no dynamic sku add from the Sub Products)

Can somebody help me with this little problem?

Maybe somebody knows a Extension to solve this Problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?